# XSL node selection thows an XPath syntax error

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm generating a PDF using Apache FOP.

I have the following XSL transformation:

```
<fo:block>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$data/mainNode/childNode/code = someFeature/someCode">
            <xsl:value-of select="$data/mainNode/childNode/[code=someFeature/someCode]/value" />                
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>Bar</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</fo:block>
```

Sample of XML structure:

```
<mainNode>
    <childNode>
        <code>A</code>
        <value>1</value>
    </childNode>
    <childNode>
        <code>B</code>
        <value>2</value>
    </childNode>
    <childNode>
        <code>C</code>
        <value>3</value>
    </childNode>
</mainNode>
```

When running it through Oxygen XML Editor I get an error saying: `XPST0003: To use XPath 3.1 syntax, you must configure the XPath parser to handle it`. The engine is Saxon-PE 9.7.0.15.

The problem is the 4th line, where I'm trying to get the value from a `childNode` with the same code as the one returned by `someFeature/someCode`.

Is there any way I can rewrite this so I won't receive an error?

Comment: There is nothing specific to XPath 3.1 in the code snippet you have posted, so the problem must be elsewhere. Please post a reproducible example - see: [mcve].

Comment: Oxygen indicates that line as the problem, so that's why I posted only that sample. Also, If I remove that line and replace it with `<xsl:text>Foo</xsl:text>` there is no error.

Comment: I don't know what Oxygen indicates, I only know what I see. And since your code is lacking context, and contains a variable defined elsewhere, it does not allow us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: The explanation for the error message is that the syntax `a/b/c/[d=5]` becomes legal in XPath 3.1, though it doesn't mean what you think it means: `[d=5]` is an array constructor that creates an array containing a single boolean value.

Comment: I'm getting a bit tired of people on StackOverflow trying to close perfectly reasonable questions.

Comment: No, it *should* have been closed, because it does not provide a way to reproduce the problem just by copy/pasting the code. I am not supposed to waste my time and strain my eyes looking for syntax errors: I have a computer to do that for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of `$data/mainNode/childNode/[code=someFeature/someCode]/value` you want `$data/mainNode/childNode[code=current()/someFeature/someCode]/value`.

Comment: Hey, Martin. Thank you for the answer, but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Consider to post a minimal but complete sample allowing us to reproduce the problem then, I am afraid I don't see why my correction would give any syntax error.

Comment: To do that I must paste almost all the XSL code, which I can't due to the NDA I've signed. Also, to paste it and replace names and values might result in a confusing code.

Comment: No, to "post a minimal but complete sample allowing us to reproduce the problem" you only need to reduce your code to something that still exhibits the problem, if it is a single line with a syntax problem then I am sure we don't need to see more than a stylesheet with a few lines of code, but a complete one.

Comment: Also, are you sure you made both corrections I made in my suggestion, namely correcting `$data/mainNode/childNode/[code` to `$data/mainNode/childNode[code` and `someFeature/someCode]/value` to `current()/someFeature/someCode]/value`? If you still have that syntax error then of course oXygen is continuing to complain.

Comment: Yes, I did add the `current()/` part and the error persists.

Comment: That second suggestion is about semantically making sense, the syntax error you get has to be fixed by the removing the `/` in `/[code`.

Comment: Sorry, Martin, I wasn't paying attention. Yes, removing the / before `[code=` fixed the problem. There is no error now.